# how to debug the protractor files?

Tags: protractor

i want to debug the protractor files. If i use --elementexplorer, it is not working. No error occurs. but if enter any commands, it is not giving any output. I have tried elementor but still not working as expected.many a times, the chrome elementor closes automatically in between and it is also not giving anything if i enter the command and submit. any suggestions?

os: windows
node version: 5+
protractor version: 6+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## --highlightDelay flag for debugging

A good way to debug protractor files is to use the [blocking proxy](https://github.com/angular/blocking-proxy) feature. The highlight delay feature will highlight your web element with css for a set amount of seconds prior to doing the action.

So you could run:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --highlightDelay 3000
```

This will highlight delay for 3 seconds in light blue before clicking a button or typing into an input field.

---

[image: blocking proxy highlight delay]

Comment: thankyou! but do you have something like elementexplorer which i can type the commands and check?

Comment: I will look into this and update you. I don't know about elementexplorer.

Comment: thankyou @cnishina please refer - http://blog.ng-book.com/interactive-protractor-repl-with-elementexplorer/ it looks like great option but it is not working in my VM. looks like os compatibility issue. same is happening for elementor also.so, i have to look for other option.

Comment: I wrote "I don't know about elementexplorer"... I think what I meant to say was, I don't know the state of elementexplorer. Anyway, I asked another maintainer, elementexplorer works in 5.0.0. They said 5.1.1 does not work and could be because of a PR that affects the controlflow. If you need elementexplorer, try 5.0.0. If you are using AngularJS, elementor should work. If you are using Angular, elementor will not work.

Comment: ok sorry for the wrong perception.Thanks for checking and letting me know. I will try with 5.0 and let you know.