# Angular2 + Protractor test running with no result

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm starting simple Protractor test for an Angular 2 app which looks like this:

```
    import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';

    describe('My Page', function() {
      it('should load news block', () => {
        browser.get('/my/page');

        element(by.id('news')).getText().then(function(text) {
          expect(text.length > 0).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

as a result system runs the browser, goes to the required page and I can't see a result - if test executed successfully. In console I always see 'Spec started' message.

[image]

What I do wrong?

Protractor config file:

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 2500000,
    specs: [
        './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 2500000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    beforeLaunch: function() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e'
        });
    },
    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide your protractor-config file ;-)

Comment: Added config file.. Note - if I check for expect(true).toBe(true), all works well and fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should have logged a period for a passed test; however, since you are using a `SpecReporter`, this may override the default reporter to console. There are two ways you can debug this:

1. You can use the cool and new BlockingProxy feature. This feature should highlight the element before getting the text. You can read about how to do it here: [how to debug the protractor files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594641/how-to-debug-the-protractor-files/43599502#43599502)
2. I believe there are a few cases where BlockingProxy will not highlight the element. If that is the case, you could try a couple of things to debug:

---

(updating answer for more logging):

```
  console.log('we are going to find the news id');
  element(by.id('news')).getText().then(text => {
    // If we do have text, let's log it so we know we got to this block of code.
    console.log('Pass! We have text: ' + text);
    expect(text.length > 0).toBeTruthy();
  }).catch(err => {
    // Else we could not fid the 'news' id, so we should log an error.
    console.log('The id for news could not be found.);
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: I've tried to debug using console.log().. however when I press F12 to get browser console opened, my protractor tests were closed with this error - http://prntscr.com/fhotaj

Comment: console.log should print to the area where the test is running. So after it says `Running 1 instance` you should be able to see some logging. I updated the answer to have one more line of logging. If you do not see this line in the window, something else is wrong.

Comment: so, when I do console.log in protractor test it should print message in Windows console, not in Browser console?

Comment: Yup, that's what it should do. I would also comment out / remove the onPrepare plugin in your protractor configuration file. Also, one last question. Does it actually navigate to your '/my/page'?

Comment: Just executed your code and at least can see message 'we are going to find the news id'. But nothing else :(

Comment: Revisiting this. Have you tried this? I have an example of using a junit reporter (https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/blob/master/jasmine-junit-reports/conf.js). Could be a good way to verify if the SpecReporter is overriding the default reporter. Have you also tried removing the SpecReporter portion to make sure that it is logging?